# Pass value of href from JSP to Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, href

> I am working on **Java EE application** where I want to pass my **selected href
>   value from JSP to a Servlet**. I have 5 links from which i want to pass
>   selected value.
>
> My **jsp code** is,

```
<a href="selectTopic" name="html">HTML 5</a><br />
                <a href="selectTopic" name="windows">Windows 8</a><br />
                <a href="selectTopic" name="office">MS Office 2013</a><br />
                <a href="selectTopic" name="android">Android</a><br />
                <a href="selectTopic" name="hadoop">Hadoop</a>
```

> which look like this

[image]

> I have mapped my selectTopic action to the **SelectedTopic.java** servlet
>   class. code is,

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String selectedTopic = "";

        selectedTopic = (String)request.getParameter("html");

        System.out.println("selectedTopic = "+selectedTopic);

    }
```

> and the **output** is:

```
selectedTopic = null
```

> My question is,
>
> 1)Why i am getting null value as i have taken same as we are getting
>   value from any textfield
>   2)How can i dynamically differentiate and
>   take selected link name (html or windows or android etc) on
>   SelectedTopic.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using request.getRequestURL():

```
String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
```

Or you can add some keywords at the end of the anchor, like "selectTopic?q=windows and analyze the querystring (recommended):

```
String urlWithQueryString = request.getRequestURL().append("?").append( 
     request.getQueryString()).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML [forms][1] are used to pass data to a server.


<form>
.
input elements
.
</form>
```

And `Href` is not there in the  [List](http://www.files.chem.vt.edu/chem-ed/CHP/workshops/samples/formlist.html)

Either you have to use `query string` or   [hidden parameters](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms07.htm).